# How can i uninstall (and reinstall) misbehaving Preview on Mac?

Tags: preview, gmail, screen-capture, attachments

Previously I took screenshots with Preview (comes with Mac), then embedded those images inline in text body of gmails.  Suddenly now, Gmail insisting on their being attachments only, and often the attachment downloads on the other end as a corrupt file (even tho the screenshot looks fine upon first snapping).  I would like to update Preview or uninstall and reinstall it, but can see no way to do that.  Also don't know whether is is a Gmail issue or a Preview issue?

Comment: This is a Gmail issue.  Preview does what it says it does - it "Previews" images, documents, etc.  It doesn't do anything (besides minor edits and annotations) to the image where Gmail would make them attachments versus images.  You would have the same issue if you opened an image in Photoshop and tried to attach it in Gmail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about Apple hardware, software or services as defined in the [Help] but about an issue concerning Gmail.

Comment: It is unlikely that an application would 'corrupt' itself so as to be working perfectly, but 'incorrectly'. E.g. starting some unwelcome behaviour, but not crashing. OS-bundled apps are on a read-only volume, and unlikely to alter. "reinstalling" is rarely a fix for problems, which are usually caused by incorrect preferences and interactions with other apps.

Comment: btw, Screenshots from Preview merely invoke the Screenshot app [Applications/Utilities] the same as Cmd/shift/ 3, 4 or 5. Use Cmd/Shift/5 to define screenshot parameters.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this - however, i will share that after i sent this query, i tried doing this same manipulation on a laptop and on another desktop and there was no issue whatsoever.  it worked just as it has for several years:  Preview Screenshot ("from selection"), save to desktop as jpg/etc, then drag into inline text, and Gmail works fine, no problem at all.  so as the problem only occurs on a single desktop (i have also tried installing an updated operating system, but to no avail) this would seem to indicate that the problem is in fact within that particular Preview software, right?